# contents of ouput file of "script" command is cryptic

Tags: shell, scripting

When I run a script to log the entire console, the output file is crytpic with symbols like `^[d ^M ^[ ^@ ^@` etc. Is there an editor which will remove and open the file that looks like exact console logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sir, your editor is sed. :D

Try the following command:

```
$ sed -E "s/[[:cntrl:]](\[K[0-9]? ?)?//g" your_file_here > output_file
```

That should remove all of the control characters (the characters you described) from your file.

Comment: The `-e` is required for combining multiple commands. When you have just one command (as in this case, the part between double quotes) it is not required.

Comment: I used -E for the extended version of regular expressions. From the sed man page:

"-E: Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats."